# "No such path or directory exists" error was thrown and job went to MSGW even when the file exists in IFS folder

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have used a cpysplf command and copied the spool file to IFS folder as .pdf file. When I am trying to fetch the .pdf file and send through e-mail, "No such path or directory exists" error was thrown and the job went to MSGW.
Spool got copied in the IFS folder and it has proper authority. What could be the possible reason for this? And this issue I faced only for once. There are other spools that didn't throw any error.

I have checked the job log. I could see in the job log that the spool is copied and checked in IFS if the file is there with proper authority.

Comment: Check for spelling errors on the path, or for spaces on the ends of the names. RPG uses fixed length fields, and you can get spaces on the ends of names that can mess up the whole works.

Comment: Depending on how the PDF gets generated, you could also be trying to access it too quickly.  We've had issues on our system where the file gets "created" but we can't actually open it yet due to their still being locks on the IFS file.  If you try the exact same command later, it will work.  We've written a program to ensure the file exists and can be grabbed with an exclusive lock before we consider the file to be available to access.

Comment: If the lock exists on the file, error message will not be "No such path or directory exists" right ?

Comment: Is there any way to find the name of the file sent ? In the dump I could see the values for those variables of the calling program. I couldn't see the dump for the actual program which received the error.

Comment: You would think so on the error message but no.  We got the "No such path..." error message on our system.  Without the dump or being able to run it in debug, I don't know of a way to see the actual value in the program.  Are you running it by SBMJOB or calling it directly from CL or RPG?

Comment: I am running it as a SBMJOB